# Problem with implementing Delete at Position function in Doubly Linked Lists

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

I'm trying to code out the functions for *Doubly Linked Lists* and am running into problems implementing the *Delete at Position* function.

It works as expected for the deletion of nodes in the first and last positions.

However, for the deletion of intermediate positions,  it deletes it as expected the first time (at least on the surface, that is how it appears), the next time, however, it enters a garbage value for the intermediate position.

My *Delete at Position* function:

```
void delete_pos(struct node **p, int pos)
{
    struct node *q;
    q=*p;

    int i=1;

    while((q->next!=NULL)&&(i<pos))
        {
            q=q->next;
            i++;
        }

    if(q==NULL)   //empty list or invalid position
        printf("Invalid Position\n");

    else //position found
    {
        if(q->prev==NULL)    //1st position
        {
            if(q->next==NULL)  //only 1 node
                *p=NULL;

            else    //more than 1 node 
            {
                q->next->prev=NULL;
                *p=q->next;
            }
        }

        else if(q->next!=NULL)  //intermediate position
        {
            printf("Yes\n");    //debugging check to make sure that it's going to the right condition
            q->prev->next=q->next;
        }
        
        else //last position
            q->prev->next=NULL;  //

        free(q);
    }
}
```

Example of the problem I have with the output:

```
1<->2<->3<->4<->5<->NULL
```

is my Doubly Linked List.

If I call *Delete at Position* function and enter an intermediate value:

```
Enter position
2
1<->3<->4<->5<->NULL
```

It appears to works as expected the first time.
However, the next time I call:

```
Enter the position..
2
1<->6564704<->4<->5<->NULL
```

In another attempt it behaved weirdly as it didn't produce garbage value, it just didn't work the second time, the output:

```
1<->3<->4<->5<->NULL

Enter the position..
2
1<->4<->5<->NULL

Enter the position..
2
1<->4<->5<->NULL

Enter the position..
2
1<->4<->5<->NULL
```

My debugging attempt:
Through a print statement, I made sure that its' going into the intermediate condition :

```
else if(q->next!=NULL)  //intermediate position
        {
            printf("Yes\n");    //debugging check to make sure that it's going to the right condition
            q->prev->next=q->next;
        }
```

And it was, however I cannot figure how the statement:

```
q->prev->next=q->next;
```

is wrong for intermediate position node deletion in a doubly linked list, as that is the only thing that stands out that could be going wrong.

Thank you for your time for reading this!

Answer (score 0):

When deleting an intermediate node you do

```
q->prev->next=q->next;
```

which means that you make the node before q point to the node after q.

That is fine but since it is a doubly linked list you also need to make the node after q point to the node before q.

Something like:

```
q->prev->next=q->next;
q->next->prev=q->prev;
```

*Further explanation:*

If we draw your list like:

```
----------       ----------       ----------
|        |       |        |       |        |
|    next|------>|    next|------>|    next|
|   NB   |       |   Q    |       |   NA   |
|prev    |<------|prev    |<------|prev    |
|        |       |        |       |        |
----------       ----------       ----------
```

then you do

```
q->prev->next=q->next;
```

which change the list into

```
               --------------
----------    /  ----------  \    ----------
|        |   /   |        |   \-->|        |
|    next|--/    |    next|------>|    next|
|   NB   |       |   Q    |       |   NA   |
|prev    |<------|prev    |<------|prev    |
|        |       |        |       |        |
----------       ----------       ----------
```

But that is only half of the pointers. You also need

```
q->next->prev=q->prev;
```

to get

```
               --------------
----------    /  ----------  \    ----------
|        |   /   |        |   \-->|        |
|    next|--/    |    next|------>|    next|
|   NB   |       |   Q    |       |   NA   |
|prev    |<------|prev    |    ---|prev    |
|        |<-\    |        |   /   |        |
----------   \   ----------  /    ----------
              ---------------
```

Now you can delete Q to get

```
               --------------
----------    /              \    ----------
|        |   /                \-->|        |
|    next|--/                     |    next|
|   NB   |                        |   NA   |
|prev    |                     ---|prev    |
|        |<-\                 /   |        |
----------   \               /    ----------
              ---------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever deleting from Linked Lists, always start from right and move towards left.

Suppose here `p` is the node you want to delete, then assume your list as

`1-2-3-4-5`

Now suppose you want to delete the node `3` then let `p` be that node.

Now do,

`p-> right{4} -> left{3 at the moment} = p -> left{2 at the moment}`

`p-> left{2} -> right{3 at the moment} = p-> right{4}`

`p->left = NULL`
`p->right = NULL`

With this your deletion will be done, you can additionally free the memory of `p` if you want to.

This might seem tricky at first so I recommend you to try it on paper, follow the 3 steps above and your deletion will work.

Answer (score 0):

The function invokes undefined behavior when initially the expression `*p` is a null pointer that is when the function deals with an empty list due to accessing memory using this null pointer

```
void delete_pos(struct node **p, int pos)
{
    struct node *q;
    q=*p;

    int i=1;

    while((q->next!=NULL)&&(i<pos))
           ^^^^^^^^
    //...
```

You need to check whether the list is empty in the very beginning of the function before the while loop.

After the while loop

```
while((q->next!=NULL)&&(i<pos))
    {
        q=q->next;
        i++;
    }
```

if the list initially is not empty when the pointer `q` can not be equal to `NULL` because the next value is assigned to the pointer only when the condition `q->next!=NULL` is true.  That means that the user can specify a non-existent  position (for example a too big position) but the last node will be in any case deleted.  Or the user of the function can pass a negative number as a value of the position and in this case the first node will be deleted.

The parameter that specifies the position should be declared as having an unsigned integer type for example `size_t` and positions should start from zero.

The function should report whether a node in a given position was successfully deleted. That is the function should be declared like

```
int delete_pos( struct node **p, size_t pos );
```

In case when the deleted node is not the head or tail node then you forgot to update the data member `prev` of the next node after the deleted node.

```
    else if(q->next!=NULL)  //intermediate position
    {
        printf("Yes\n");    //debugging check to make sure that it's going to the right condition
        q->prev->next=q->next;
    }
```

You updated only the data member next of the node before the deleted node.

The function can look the following way

```
int delete_pos( struct node **head, size_t pos )
{
    while ( *head && pos-- )
    {
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }
    
    int success = *head != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        struct node *current = *head;
        
        if ( ( *head )->next != NULL )
        {
            ( *head )->next->prev = ( *head )->prev;
        }

        *head = ( *head )->next;    
        
        free( current );
    }
    
    return success;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows the function in action.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
};

size_t create( struct node **head, const int a[], size_t n )
{
    while ( *head )
    {
        struct node *current = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( current );
    }
    
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( struct node *prev = NULL; 
          i != n && ( *head = malloc( sizeof( **head ) ) ) != NULL;
          i++ )
    {
        ( *head )->data = a[i];
        ( *head )->prev = prev;
        ( *head )->next = NULL;
        
        prev = *head;
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }
    
    return i;
}

void display( const struct node *head )
{
    const struct node *tail = NULL;
    
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
        tail = head;
    }
    
    puts( "null" );
    
    for ( ; tail != NULL; tail = tail->prev )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", tail->data );
    }
    
    puts( "null" );
}

int delete_pos( struct node **head, size_t pos )
{
    while ( *head && pos-- )
    {
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }
    
    int success = *head != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        struct node *current = *head;
        
        if ( ( *head )->next != NULL )
        {
            ( *head )->next->prev = ( *head )->prev;
        }

        *head = ( *head )->next;    
        
        free( current );
    }
    
    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    
    create( &head, a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );
    
    display( head );
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    delete_pos( &head, 0 );
    
    display( head );
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    delete_pos( &head, 3 );
    
    display( head );
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    delete_pos( &head, 1 );
    
    display( head );
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    delete_pos( &head, 1 );
    
    display( head );
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    delete_pos( &head, 0 );
    
    display( head );
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> null

2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> null

2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
4 -> 3 -> 2 -> null

2 -> 4 -> null
4 -> 2 -> null

2 -> null
2 -> null

null
null
```